# Why drawable color filter is applied in all places?

Tags: android, android-drawable

In a section of my app I need my drawable `R.drawable.blah` to be filtered to white color (originally is red), so I have this method:

```
public final static Drawable getFilteredDrawable(Context context, @DrawableRes int drawable, @ColorRes int color) {
    Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawable);
    d.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    return d;
}
```

and I use it this way:

```
DrawableUtil.getFilteredDrawable(this, R.drawable.blah, android.R.color.white);
```

Problem is that now the drawable becomes white in the whole app, even not applying the filter. I want the drawable to be white just in this section of the app, but it is in each place I use it, instead.

How can I solve it?

Comment: you are modifying The drawable, not a copy. You should create a copy of this drawable in your resources, for example, to solve your issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use this method instead, to be sure you're using a copy of your drawable

```
public final static Drawable  getFilteredDrawable(Context context, @DrawableRes int drawable, @ColorRes int color) {
    Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawable).getConstantState().newDrawable().mutate(); //so we are sure we are using a copy of the original drawable
    d.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    return d;
}
```

Comment: This is saved me. Thanks a lot :)