# change color of drawale in Menu

Tags: android, xml, menu, background-color, menuitem

I have here an Menu in my app:

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_ok"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>  </menu>
```

I want to know if i can change the color of the ic_ok drawable. Because default its black but i need a white one. I know that i can download a new one from the internet in white color and take it but i wanted to know if i can change the color in the xml code.

I tried all me known commands like:

```
android:tint="@color/white" 
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:backgroundColor="@color/white"
android:color="@color/white"
```

But nothing works.

Thanks for your time
Daniel

Comment: is this a part of `NavigationView` because I know there you can change the color of the drawable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the another way..

> right click on drawable directory --> new --> select vector asset -->
>   click to choose button --> select your particular icon --> press ok.
>   now icon appear in drawable.. select that your icon's xml file.. and
>   here you can change fillColor of your icon, and other things like opacity height, wight

Answer (score 0):

**programmatically**, you can get the drawable and color it with white :)

```
// I suppose your drawable object variable it named drawable
drawable.getConstantState().newDrawable().mutate(); //so we are sure we are using a copy of the original drawable
drawable.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
// now you can use the drawable in your source code
```

this solution is based on [one of the answers I already made](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38786136/3178454)